# Postgresql SQL: How check boolean field with null and True,False Value?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, sql-null

In my database table I am having one boolean column, which have some rows with False, True and Null.

These are the cases I have tried:

**Case 1:**

```
select * from table_name where
boolean_column is null;
```

works well. Give the result with all rows having null value for that column.

**Case 2:**

```
select *from table_name where boolean_column = False;
```

Works well. Gives result with all the rows having False value for that column.

**Case 3:**

This is requirement which does not works. I want all the rows having values False and Null.

I have tried these.

i)  `select *from table_name where boolean_column is False or Null;`

*Which only gives the result for False it does not shows null records.*

ii) `select *from table_name where boolean_column is Null or False;`

*Which only gives the result for null it does not shows records with False value.*

iii) `select *from table_name where boolean_column is Null or boolean_column = False;`

*This simply displays all the rows, it does not apply any condition at all.*

What query can solve this problem?

Comment: The `or` in `boolean_column is False or Null` does not apply to `boolean_column` being `null` but whether `boolean_column is False` is TRUE OR `Null` is TRUE.  Obviously not what your intending.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use the `IS NOT TRUE` operator:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE boolean_column IS NOT TRUE;
```

This will match values which are either false or `NULL`.  Another option would be to use a `UNION` of the two queries which you know do work:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE boolean_column IS NULL
UNION
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE boolean_column = FALSE
```

You could also try using `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE COALESCE(boolean_column, FALSE) = FALSE
```

This third query will replace all `NULL` values with `FALSE` and then compare against `FALSE` in the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: My Query is not single line. I have more than 20 Conditions Query is about 1 page. do I have to Repeat the same query again?

Comment: This is a poor answer - there is no need to run two queries.

Answer (score 176):

There are 3 states for boolean in PG: true, false and unknown (null). Explained here: [Postgres boolean datatype](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-boolean.html)

Therefore you need only query for NOT TRUE:

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE boolean_column IS NOT TRUE;
```

Answer (score 13):

On PostgreSQL you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (boolean_column IS NULL OR NOT boolean_column)
```

Answer (score 8):

1. `select *from table_name where boolean_column is False or Null;`

   Is interpreted as "( boolean_column is False ) or (null)".

   It returns only rows where `boolean_column` is False as the second condition is always false.
2. `select *from table_name where boolean_column is Null or False;`

   Same reason. Interpreted as "(boolean_column is Null) or (False)"
3. `select *from table_name where boolean_column is Null or boolean_column = False;`

   This one is valid and returns 2 rows: `false` and `null`.

I just created the table to confirm. You might have typoed somewhere.

Answer (score 8):

Resurrecting this to post the `DISTINCT FROM` option, which has been around since [Postgres 8](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/functions-comparison.html). The approach is similar to Brad Dre's answer. In your case, your select would be something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE boolean_column IS DISTINCT FROM TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

@Brad Dre's answer is the least code and same efficiency as this one, but potentially harder to understand for future developers. Chris's third and Dmitry's answers already covered this, but I wanted to add an answer with a bit more background.

In the OP's words:

"I want all the transactions having value False and Null."

Re-worded in almost-sql:

"I want all the transactions where the value is False or the value is Null."

Re-worded into SQL:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM transactions
WHERE 
    value IS FALSE 
    OR value IS NULL;
```

Often writing the code to be as close as natural language as possible will give future developers hints on the intention of the initial developer. The issue with @Brad Dre's anwser is a future developer might not think of the NULL case in Brad's code, or might have thought Brad forgot about it.